# How do I prove that the empty set is not open or closed using a proof by contradiction(not vacuously) in a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I am generally unsatisfied with the vacuous proof techniques as they can be unilluminating. I have tried to construct a proof by contradiction to justify that the empty set is open without resorting to vacuous proof or other using the property of compliments of open and closed sets. Would the proof outlined below be a valid proof by contradiction that the empty set is open.

**Proof** (contradiction): Let $T = \emptyset$ and assume that T is not open, then there exists an $x \in T$  such that there is and epsilon neighborhood where $N(x,\epsilon) \cap T^c \nsubseteq \emptyset$, this is a false since since $x \in T$,implies $ T \neq \emptyset$ so we were wrong to assume that $T = \emptyset$ was not open and thus it is open.

Comment: This is a vacuous proof. It's really unavoidable with the empty set.

Comment: The defining property of the empty set is that it has no elements, and you're essentially asking for a proof that doesn't use the fact that the empty set has no elements. There's not really anything left to say about the empty set, other than it being the complement of the entire space (which amounts to the same thing), which you've also barred.

Comment: I've seen proofs for the empty set being the subset of every set done by contradiction would a similar proof be possible here @JonathanHebert

Comment: In a metric space containing points $a \neq b$ you could take the open neighborhoods around each of $a$ and $b$ with radius $|a-b|/2$. Since the intersection of two open sets is open, the intersection of these two open neighborhoods -- i.e., the empty set -- is open.

Comment: You might consider amending the title since you're attempting to prove the opposite.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman yes, but in a metric space the proof that the intersection of two open sets is open relies on the fact that the empty set is open (namely, in the case when the open sets are disjoint). That sounds like circular logic.

Comment: @JonathanHebert I was thinking that the definition of a topology generally includes that the intersection of finitely many open sets is open; but, the definition also includes that the empty set is, itself, open. I'm not sure what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof by contradiction is good for the open part. But you also need to show that it is not closed. You can't really do a proof by contradiction for this part and you will need to use a vacuous proof I think.

Comment: When can you not write a proof by contradiction? "Suppose the empty set is not closed. Then there exists a limit point of the empty set that is not in the empty set. This is a contradiction because the empty set has no limit points. Thus the empty set is closed."?